# Unable to access WCF Service using InfoPath

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl, infopath

I am consuming wcf service using infopath, I can easily access it through IE, but unable to access using InfoPath,
my wcf service is hosted on another server. I am getting this error :

```
WSDLReader:Could not find '/definitions/service' inside the '' namespace of the wsdl file. The parameter is incorrect.
 - WSDLReader:Analyzing the WSDL file failed. The parameter is incorrect.
```

It was all working fine, but when server was restarted or shutdown, it has stopped working and am getting this error now. When I deployed the same webservice on the same server where my InfoPath form is, it was working fine.

Comment: how did you create the webservice? is it specificly designed for SP?

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty Infopah cache on client

How to  do it more specifically depends on Windows and Infopath version/edition which were not  given